# What metadata keys are available in Everyplay?

Tags: unity-game-engine, everyplay

On the Everyplay Unity3D guide page these three lines are given as an example of using metadata with Everyplay.

```
Everyplay.SharedInstance.SetMetadata("level", levelNumber);
Everyplay.SharedInstance.SetMetadata("level_name", levelName);
Everyplay.SharedInstance.SetMetadata("score", score)
```

Are there any other metadata keys available than those three? Can you define your own metadata for your game instead of just using predefined keys? Could not find any more documentation on this than the above mentioned example.

Answer (score 1):

You can and should provide as much metadata about the video as you can as there are several features to use the data already under work. The metadata supplied with the video has several intended (future) purposes. Currently only score and level_name are displayed with the videos on Everyplay (for example: http://everyplay.com/videos/8106 ).

The developer can (in the near future) configure what metadata to show with the videos, a racing game could show time, circuit and laps and an FPS game might show kills and deaths. Also we are already developing features into our API to allow developers to use the metadata to query existing videos, for example fetching a list of videos from level 1 in the past 10 days sorted by "score" and so on.

For a quick example here is the metadata that stair dismount (the video in the link above) provided with the same video:

```
metadata: {
    somersaults: 1,
    level: 60,
    decapitation: false,
    bifurcation: false,
    push_force_z: -3957.182,
    push_force_y: 1773.326,
    distance: -1,
    push_pos_z: 8.371746,
    push_force_x: -1675.732,
    push_pos_y: 24.18944,
    push_body_name: "LeftForearm",
    ragdoll_custom_face: true,
    push_pos_x: -0.6025434,
    push_body_id: 2189472344,
    leaderboard_id: 1208019,
    score: 3802645,
    level_name: "Revolting Doors",
    ragdoll_breakability: false,
    distance_leaderboard_id: 0,
    ragdoll_name: "Mr. Dismount",
    ragdoll: 0
}
```

Comment: Also, as a developer you can now login to https://developers.everyplay.com and select specific formatting rules for the metadata keys you want to present within video page.